# networkmanager and dns resolution

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I would like to understand how DNS resolution works on my machine.

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)`. My network connection is set up via NetworkManager:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

This should set up `dnsmasq` as my DNS server.

```bsh
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fritz.box corp.net
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

If I do a `nslookup`, it indicates that it is using dnsmasq:

```bsh
nslookup example.org
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.org
Address: 93.184.216.34
Name:   example.org
Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```

But, if I use the `nmcli` to query the DNS server ip addresses it shows the ip addresses of my router:

```bsh
nmcli dev show enxcc483ab34466 | grep -i dns
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd00::2e91:abff:fe96:3f60
```

I assume these settings are ignored, when I configure `NetworkManager` with `dns=dnsmasq`. Is that correct?

Assuming this is correct, I am trying to understand which DNS servers `dnsmasq` uses:

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep dnsmasq
libvirt+    2276  0.0  0.0   9252  2024 ?        S    Apr04   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
root        2278  0.0  0.0   9224   332 ?        S    Apr04   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
nobody      4264  0.0  0.0  15128  4540 ?        S    Apr04   0:08 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
root      401382  0.0  0.0   9380  2824 pts/1    S+   18:54   0:00 grep --color=auto dnsmasq
```

The first two processes are from `libvirt` and, according to the config file `/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf` only bind to a virtual interface. I do not know why there are two processes though.

The third process with the ip address 127.0.1.1 gets all its config from the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`. `cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/*` returns only ip addresses to my companys DNS servers. These can only be reached inside a VPN connection.

How is it possible that I can resolve DNS names without the VPN connection? Did I miss something? Is `dnsmasq` somehow using the DNS server from my `NetworkManager` device settings?